# logging in to a site using cURL with rails and maintain the session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I need help in making a POST Request using cURL inside my rails controller, that has the ability to send authentication information and maintain the session in a cross domain site.

I have tried [Rack Cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to no avail. I added the gem and the necessary configuration.

Tried javascript ajax way

```
$('.test-btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : "https://xxyyzz.com/login/do_login",
        data       : {
            user_id : user_id,
            password: password
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

but i get `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error

i tried the `Net::HTTP` way

```
uri      = URI.parse("https://xxyyzz/login/do_login")
http     = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request  = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data({"user_id" => "xxx", "password" => "yyy"})
request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

response = http.request(request)
```

but i get `EOFError (end of file reached)`

I am completely lost, can anyone point me to the right direction? I am not limiting on a specific way, it can be anything as long it can be used in a Ruby on Rails Project.

Comment: Why dont you try `Postman`?. It is easy and efficient

Comment: i am not trying to test my application with a post request, i'm trying to build one that do a post request login on an external site, and maintain the session login for other tasks to manipulate that external site i'm trying to login.